# Trouble with moving cube

Tags: unity-game-engine

At the moment I have a cube on the screen, now it is moving forward but only when I press and release the key 'd' on the keyboard. Its like it is not updating quick enough.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("d")){
            currentSpeed.x = 100;   
            rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(accelaration, 0, 0);
        }
```

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: If you're looking for continuous movement, use `Input.GetKey`, `GetKeyDown` only fires on the initial keypress.

Comment: Appending to the ^ comment, if you're doing this inside Update, you should multiply acceleration (not with the 'a' btw) by time.deltaTime, that way your game isn't frame-dependent. You don't need to if you're doing it inside FixedUpdate, which you should because you're dealing with physics-related stuff (adding force).

Comment: I have noticed the same keyboard lag (up to ~300ms) in scenes graphically intensive enough to cause framerate drops.

Answer (score 0):

This is might be working,

```
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.position+=-transform.right*speed;

    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.position+=transform.right*speed;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.position+=transform.forward*speed;

    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        transform.position+=-transform.forward*speed;
    }
```